# Irreducible representations and invariant subspace

Tags: group-theory

We are given a representation of $S_3$ on vector space V. $x$ and $y$ are usual generators of $S_3$.

If a is a non-zero vector in $V$ such that $b=a+xa+x^2a$ and $c=a+ya$. Show that $V$ contains a nonzero invariant subspace of dimension at most 2

My attempt: I was thinking about G-orbits of $b$ and $c$ and maybe we can get an answer from that? So I considered the conjugates of $b$ and $c$ that is multiplied by $gbg^{-1}$ and $gcg^{-1}$ where $g\in S_3$. But I am really stuck on where to go on from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Assuming $x = (1 \ 2 \ 3)$ and $y = (1 \ 2)$ then $yx = x^2y$.  First assume $b \neq 0$ and use that relation to show that the span of $\{b, yb\}$ is invariant.

Next assume that $b = 0$ but $c \neq 0$ and show that $c + xc + x^2c = 0$.  Use this to show that the span of $\{c, xc\}$ is an invariant subspace.

Finally assume that $b = c = 0$.  Show that $\{a, xa\}$ spans an invariant subspace.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I am able to show all the conditions required. However I am not able that the span $\{c,xc\}$ is invariant. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Have you been able to show that $c + xc + x^2c = 0$?

Comment: Yes I am able to show that.

Comment: So then you can see that the space spanned by $c$ and $xc$ is invariant under the action of $x$.  To see that it's invariant under the action of $y$ use $yx = x^2y$ to move $y$ inside (next to $c$) and then use $yc = c$.

Comment: @Jim, could you clarify what we need to show if $b=0$ and $c=0$? I get understand that by the end of the calculation we will have shown that $\text{span}\{a,xa\}$ is an invariant subspace, but I'm not sure how to use the relations $a+xa+x^2a=0$ and $a+ya=0$.