# on definition of dimension of group representation

Tags: abstract-algebra

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588402/irreducible-representations-and-invariant-subspace) question, why cannot the representation be the map from the group $G$ to the identity in any n-dimensional space $V$? That is a homomorphism, and it fixes everything in $V$, which can have dimension greater than 2.

Comment: the point in that problem isn't that $S_3$ can't have representations of dimension $>2$ (indeed, extending your example, any group can have representations of any dimension by taking all elements to act trivially). the point is that $S_3$ can't have *irreducible* representations of dimension $>2$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom $S_3$ has three irreps of dimensions 1, 1, and 2.

Comment: @Joppy oops, you're of course right, corrected

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom OK, but where do you get that from the problem statement? I don't see any mention of irreducibility. Are representations assumed to be irreducible unless stted otherwise?

Comment: @savemo the problem is just to show that, given an arbitrary representation $V$ of $S_3$, you can find a subrepresentation of $V$ of dimension $\leqslant 2$

Comment: in your example, where $S_3$ acts trivially, any two linearly independent elements of $V$ will generate a subrepresentation of $V$

Comment: what's your understanding of what the question was asking?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I read it to say that any invariant subspace is of dimension at most 2. But I guess it is just to show that there is some eigenspace of dimension at most 2?

Comment: @savemo not an eigenspace, but an $S_3$-invariant subspace. (ie, a subrepresentation). quoting: "Show that $V$ contains a nonzero invariant subspace of dimension at most 2"

Comment: (so you're asked to show that $V$ contains *a* nonzero invariant subspace of dimension at most 2, not to show that any invariant subspace is of dimension at most 2. does that make sense?)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom yup